# Items not rendering in a FlatList

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to retrieve all the data I have in my firestore database but I can't seem to accomplish it. Been trying to do for the past couple days I had no luck. The data doesn't seem to be retrieving at all for some reason. I did a console log of my useState() variable which is where the data should be stored, but nothing is showing. I am also new to using React Native...

```js
const [evs, setData] = useState([]);

const subscriber = firestore.collection('stations');

useEffect(() => 
  {
      return subscriber.onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
          const list = [];
          querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
            const {connectorID, connectorType} = doc.data();
            list.push({
              id: doc.id,
              connectorID,
              connectorType 
            });
          });
          setData(list);

      });
  }, []);
  
  
  console.log("LIST OF ITEMS: " + evs);

    return (
    <View>
        <Text>Charging Points Available</Text>
        <SectionList
            data={evs}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
            renderItem={({item}) => <TextComp data={item.key}/>}
        />
    </View>
  );
```

**UPDATE, Still not working..**

```js
const subscriber = firestore.collection('stations')
              .onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
                const list = [];
                   querySnapshot.forEach(documentSnapshot => {
                     list.push({
                       ...documentSnapshot.data(),
                       key: documentSnapshot.id,
                     });
                   });
                   setData(list);
                   setLoading(false);
              });
```

Answer (score 0):

> If your effect returns a function, React will run it when it is time
> to clean up

**remove return from useEffect. and try**

```
useEffect(() => 
  {
      subscriber.onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
          const list = [];
          querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
            const {connectorID, connectorType} = doc.data();
            list.push({
              id: doc.id,
              connectorID,
              connectorType 
            });
          });
          setData(list);

      });
  }, []);
```

Comment: Hi Mehran, thank you for replying to my issue. Unfortunately, I'm still getting an empty list when I removed the return keyword.